# Android instant & installable app set different version code

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have an android app with instant feature. I want to set versionCode 1 for instant app and versionCode 1000 for installable app.
I have 3 build.gradle for base, installed and instant feature.

base app

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mypackage"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = '1.0.0'
}
```

installed app

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mypackage"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode = 1000
    versionName = '1.0.0'
}
```

instant app

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mypackage"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = '1.0.0'
}
```

When building android app bundle, I am getting versionCode 1 for both instant & installable version. versionCode is always picked from base variant build.gradle.

How can I set versionCode 1000 for installable version?

I am trying to achieve this as per android documents.

**Restart the version codes for the Google Play Instant experience at 1.**

**Increase the version code of the installable APK by a large number, such as 1000, to ensure that there is enough space for your instant experience's version number to increase.**

Comment: What happens when you remove the versioncode from base gradle?